# idhttp ISO-8859-1 multipart post

Tags: encoding, delphi-2010, indy, indy10, multipartform-data

After 2 days of trying to guess right way I give up.
Lot of question with the subject but nothing helps me.

Please show me my mistake.

Task: send multipart-form (string fields and files) to server.
Server waits for ISO-8859-1 encoding.

```
    http.Request.Host := fHost;
    http.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
    http.Request.UserAgent := HTTPUserAgent;
    http.Request.ContentEncoding := 'ISO-8859-1';
//        http.Request.CharSet  := 'ISO-8859-1';
    if HTTPProxyActive then
      http.Request.ProxyConnection := 'close'
    else
      http.Request.Connection := 'close';
    http.Request.ContentType := 'text/plain';

    addr := 'https://'+Host+URL;

    if ValCount>0 then begin
      Stream := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
      for i:=0 to ValCount-1 do begin
        if Values[i].Name<>'' then
        begin
          field := Stream.AddFormField(Values[i].Name, Values[i].Value, 'ISO-8859-1');
//              field.Charset := 'ISO-8859-1';
//              field.ContentTransfer := '7bit';
        end;
        if Values[i].Filename<>'' then
          Stream.AddFile(Values[i].FileName, Values[i].Value, 'text/plain');
      end;
      resp := TStringStream.Create;
      http.Post(addr, Stream, resp);
      st := resp.DataString;
      resp.Destroy;
      Stream.Destroy;
    end
```

as result of post I have ??????? sequence on the server.
when I define charset of a field or request then I have error on server.

Please help me or what info is missing?

**UPDATE:** I can get result with UTF-8. But then in server I get UTF-8 values and I need ISO-8859-1.

UTF-8 solution:

```
field := Stream.AddFormField(Values[i].Name, Values[i].Value, 'UTF-8');
field.ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using an up-to-date version of Indy 10, then `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` works just fine with ISO-8859-1.  Simply specify that wherever you would specify UTF-8.  You also need to fix a bug with your `Request.ContentEncoding` assignment - a string charset is not a valid content encoding.  That is a completely different feature of HTTP.  And you need to get rid of the `TStringStream` as it would prevent `TIdHTTP` from decoding the response string data for you.

Try this:

```
if ValCount > 0 then
begin
  http.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
  http.Request.UserAgent := HTTPUserAgent;
  if HTTPProxyActive then
    http.Request.ProxyConnection := 'close'
  else
    http.Request.Connection := 'close';

  addr := 'https://'+Host+URL;

  Stream := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to ValCount-1 do begin
      if Values[i].Name <> '' then
      begin
        field := Stream.AddFormField(Values[i].Name, Values[i].Value, 'ISO-8859-1');
        field.ContentTransfer := '8bit';
      end;
      if Values[i].FileName <> '' then
        Stream.AddFile(Values[i].Name, Values[i].FileName, 'text/plain');
    end;
    st := http.Post(addr, Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or: more in line with the "solution" you showed:

```
if ValCount > 0 then
begin
  http.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
  http.Request.UserAgent := HTTPUserAgent;
  if HTTPProxyActive then
    http.Request.ProxyConnection := 'close'
  else
    http.Request.Connection := 'close';

  addr := 'https://'+Host+URL;

  Stream := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to ValCount-1 do begin
      if Values[i].Name <> '' then
      begin
        field := Stream.AddFormField(Values[i].Name, Values[i].Value, 'ISO-8859-1');
        field.ContentTransfer := '8bit';
        field.FileName := Values[i].FileName;
      end;
    end;
    st := http.Post(addr, Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy, thanks. But I tryed the offered way and as I remember had longer problem with ???.

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date release of Indy 10? The only way you can get `'?'` characters is if your input data uses non-ASCII characters that do not exist in ISO-8859-1. Your code is not handling that possibility. Your code ignores charsets altogether and encodes the string data using `TEncoding.Default` (that is what `TStringStream` uses internally if you don't tell it to use a different encoding). Whereas with Indy, it will acually encode the string data to whatever charset you specify, in this case ISO-8859-1.

Comment: thanks a lot. I needed very fast solution, unfortunatelly spent 3 days for it and I have no time to try some other ways. My customer have got working code. If we have future problems then I will go your way. Thanks a lot again for your great library.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Lot of solutions are in internet. Lot of solutions from Remy.
But all of them are about UTF-8.
Server can't get UTF-8 strings... And I can't get access to server-side scripts to correct situation.
So I create my request manually without TIdMultipartFormDataStream class.

I think my solution will be useful for next ones.
Good luck.

```
    http.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + FBound;
    if HTTPProxyActive then
      http.Request.ProxyConnection := 'close'
    else
      http.Request.Connection := 'close';

    addr := 'http://'+Host+URL;
    resp := TStringStream.Create;
    if ValCount>0 then
    begin
      cont := '';
      for i:=0 to ValCount - 1 do
      begin
        cont := cont + '--' + FBound + #13#10;
        cont := cont + 'Content-Disposition: form-data';
        if Values[i].Filename<>'' then
          cont := cont + '; filename="' + Values[i].Filename + '"';
        if Values[i].Name<>'' then
          cont := cont + '; name="' + Values[i].Name + '"';
        cont := cont + #13#10+#13#10;
        cont := cont + Values[i].Value;
        cont := cont + #13#10;
      end;
      cont := cont + '--' + FBound + '--' + #13#10#13#10;
      http.Request.ContentLength := Length(cont);
      req := TStringStream.Create(cont);
      http.Post(addr, req, resp);
      FreeAndNil(req);
    end
    else
    begin
      http.Get(addr, resp);
    end;
    st := resp.DataString;
    resp.Destroy;
```